# SQL to get overall average by aggregation

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a following table

```
employerid  userid
123           1321
121           1567 
126           1321
```

I want to write an SQL where I want overall average number of employerid per user id

For example

```
userid 1321 - 2 employerids (123 and 126)
userid 1567 - 1 employerid (121)
```

On an average (2 + 1) / 3 = 1.33

New to SQL. How do i write an SQL for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use both GROUPBY and AVG to get this, find an example below.

```
SELECT AVG(employer_count)
FROM (
  SELECT userid, COUNT(DISTINCT employerid) AS employer_count
  FROM your_table_name
  GROUP BY userid
) subquery;
```